# What happens to data on SD card when I update

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, windows-10-upgrade

I have Windows 10 Mobile on my Nokia Lumia 720. I wish to upgrade to latest build(with the Insider app). Will my apps be erased after I upgrade?

90% of my apps, games & game data are on external SD Card. What about the link that has been created to external SD Card for those apps/games? Will all that be safe if I upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update to the latest build without any second thoughts. *None of your data will be lost*. In-fact, some might even get newer versions supportive with that new build.